# Elements being pushed out of the parent content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the three boxes within the parent box.
I can't seem to identify the issue here. When I add the `<h3></h3>` tag within the wrapped parent box, the boxes are pushed "down" outside of the parent box. Here is what I mean.

[image]

I'm trying to put all the box elements within the colored box. Here is the HTML section of this content.

```css
.pricing {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      padding-top: 300px;
      background-color: #81F7E5;
      vertical-align: text-top
    
    }
    
    .price-box {
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-right: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #D7DAE5;
      border: black solid medium;
    }
    
    .price {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20%;
      background-color: ;
      border-bottom: black solid medium;
    }
    
    .price-box h3 {
      display: inline-block;
      color: black;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin-top: 3%;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .pricing-text {
      position: relative;
      top: -150px;
      border: solid black medium;
      display: block;
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .pricing-text h3 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: black;
      font-size: 2em;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pricing">
      <div class="pricing-text">
        <h3> Pricing </h3>
      </div>
    
      <div class="price-box">
        <div class="price">
          <h3>$9 per month</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="price-box">
        <div class="price">
          <h3>$14 per month</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="price-box">
        <div class="price">
          <h3>$20 per month</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I apologize for the long question. I am fairly new to the front-end development and any kind of advice will help me grow. Thank you so much.

Comment: Like this : http://codepen.io/pen/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this is presumptuous, but your css was quite messy. I've cleaned it up and explained in comments where I think you went wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/q9xgsqh5/1/

```
.pricing-text {
      position: relative;
      top: -150px;
```

This in particular was something I removed, instead relying on the natural flow of the html to fit everything in. While this is fine to use, it is a little messy.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is amazing. Creating a clean looking css code is something that I have been struggle with. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have great advice already. Depending on if your page needs to be responsive or not, you could wrap your markup in a parent container and add a width and height. Then use percents on the remaining code. Be careful when adding padding...remember it affects the total width and height of the container and can cause erratic effects. Lastly, I used a makeshift CSS reset. That gives you much more control over the styling. I'd recommend visiting this page as an example. http://cssreset.com/

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


#wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.pricing {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10%;
  /*height: 300px;*/
  /*padding-top: 300px;*/
  background-color: #81F7E5;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.price-box {
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  /*margin-right: 10px;*/
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #D7DAE5;
  border: black solid medium;
}

.price {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
 /* background-color: ;*/
  border-bottom: black solid medium;
}



.price-box h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

.pricing-text {
  position: relative;
  /*top: -150px;*/
  border: solid black medium;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;

}

.pricing-text h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.price h3 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="pricing">
  <div class="pricing-text">
    <h3> Pricing </h3>
  </div>

  <div class="price-box">
    <div class="price">
      <h3>$9 per month</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="price-box">
    <div class="price">
      <h3>$14 per month</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="price-box">
    <div class="price">
      <h3>$20 per month</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- end pricing -->
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a right way to do what you want to do because you will get some problems when adding content to each box. Anyway

Replace this class's height by this

```
.pricing {
    height: auto;
}
```

And add a real height to

```
.price-box {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

```css
.pricing {
     width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      /*padding-top: 300px;*/
      background-color: #81F7E5;
      vertical-align: text-top; 
    }
    
    .price-box {
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
      /*margin-right: 5px;*/
      margin: 5px 5px;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #D7DAE5;
      border: black solid medium;
      max-height:75%;
    }
    
    .price {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20%;
      background-color: ;
      border-bottom: black solid medium;
    }
    
    .price-box h3 {
      display: inline-block;
      color: black;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin-top: 3%;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .pricing-text {
      position: relative;
      /*top: -150px;*/
      border: solid black medium;
      display: block;
      /*width: 400px;*/
      height:40px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .pricing-text h3 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: black;
      font-size: 2em;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pricing">
      <div class="pricing-text">
        <h3> Pricing </h3>
      </div>
    
      <div class="price-box">
        <div class="price">
          <h3>$9 per month</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="price-box">
        <div class="price">
          <h3>$14 per month</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="price-box">
        <div class="price">
          <h3>$20 per month</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `.price-box`, you have to remove `height: 100%`;

Do it in this way:

The HTML code, adding another div with `class="content"`:

```
<div class="pricing">
  <div class="pricing-text">
  <h3> Pricing </h3>
</div>

<div class="price-box">
  <div class="price">
    <h3>$9 per month</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Text of the price-box
  </div>
</div>

<div class="price-box">
  <div class="price">
    <h3>$14 per month</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Text of the price-box
  </div>
</div>

<div class="price-box">
  <div class="price">
    <h3>$9 per month</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Text of the price-box
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.pricing {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 300px;
  background-color: #81F7E5;
  vertical-align: text-top
}

.price-box {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #D7DAE5;
  border: black solid medium;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: ;
  border-bottom: black solid medium;
}

.price-box h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pricing-text {
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  border: solid black medium;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pricing-text h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

I hope I have helped you.